# Using Geonames service and Facebook authentication in the same app (are they mutually exclusive?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, security, ssl, oauth

I have been using geonames autocomplete service with very good results while my asp.net mvc5 website was configured with an "insecure connection" (SSL Disabled - http://).

More recently, in order to integrate Facebook authentication, I was forced to change the connection type to "secure connection" (SSL Enabled - https://). Since then, when I try to access the geonames autocomplete textbox I get the following error: **"Oops, geonames service returned an error".**

I went to the **geonames** website and I realized that **only the premium account (payed) allows secure connections.**

Do you have any idea on **how I can keep using the geonames service while allowing facebook authentication at the same time (for free)?** I'm pretty sure there must be a workaround to get things done. I don't need a final answer, I would be satisfied with some insight on how this could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way: Stopped using GeoNames autocomplete and started using Google Places autocomplete instead.